# Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory throws an exception during Checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, shopping-cart

I'm using the theme -

> https://themeforest.net/item/multistores-magento-2-megashop-theme-support-multiple-stores/19211690?s_rank=17

I purchased the theme from themeforest and had the application set up on a hosting. I'm using Magento ver. 2.1.1. After adding products into the shopping cart, when I clicked checkout, it threw an exception:

```
Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory in /home/shopegiv/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73
```

I tried to resolve the same by putting this line in **app/etc/di.xml**:

```
< preference for="Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory" type="Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer" />
```

Thereafter, the fatal error went away, but now I get the following error in **var/log/system.log**:

> Argument 15 passed to
>   Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Transparent::__construct() must implement
>   interface Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceIFactory,
>
> instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer
>   given, called in
>   /home/shopegiv/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>
> on line 93 and defined in
>   /home/shopegiv/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Payflow/Transparent.php
>   on line 99 [] []

The output displayed on the screen was Object **DOMDocument** should be created.

I assume I'm not going the right direction to specify the preference or specify concrete factory such as `AccountPaymentTokenFactory` or `CreditCardTokenFactory`.

If someone could advice the workarounds split into steps, I shall be thankful.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: are you using any third party payment module?

Comment: Hi @sunilpatel

I appreciate you taking time to look into my concern.

I haven't incorporated any third party payment module additionally yet, just have put up the theme on Magento ver. 2.1.1.

Comment: removed var/generation and var/cache.var/di
switched to developer mode to recompile

Comment: I just followed what you suggested @sunilpatel but I get this on the screen after I click on the "Cart" link.

Argument 15 passed to Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Transparent::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer given, called in /home/shopegiv/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /home/shopegiv/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Payflow/Transparent.php on line 100

Answer (score 0):

Compare your file with 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.6/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Payflow/Transparent.php

and copy same file and check it.

Comment: I copied the file you suggested into vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Payflow/Transparent.php

Still I get this error:

Argument 15 passed to Magento\Paypal\Model\Payflow\Transparent::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer given, called in /home/shopegiv/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /home/shopegiv/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Payflow/Transparent.php on line 89

Comment: after copy please remove var/cache.var/generation, var/di

Comment: Even thereafter, it's the same exception that comes up. Removed the items from var/ just as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could figure it out myself.

There's no need to set the preference in `app/etc/di.xml`.

In `/home/shopegiv/public_html/dev/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Payflow/Transparent.php`, instead of using `\Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory` in the constructor, rather use `\Magento\Vault\Model\PaymentTokenFactory` and it solves the issue.